# VBA Word: Faster copy from many files in directory?

Tags: vba, performance, ms-word, macros

After reading many sources and copying-pasting a lot I have come up with a macro for MS Word 2010 to calculate my work done at the end of the day.

**What it does:**

1. Opens each DOCX file in a specified directory.
2. Copies text from the right part of a two-column table that I use for translations.
3. Opens the statistics file and pastes clipboard at the top of the file.
4. When no more files are left to process, the macro prints statistics at the top of the statistics file.

It works all right. However, I'd love to make it work faster. If I use the macro to process like 50-100 files, it may slow down after 10-15 to 1 file per second perhaps. I am at a loss. I guess I didn't choose the right tool for the job. **Can I make this code run faster?**

I've tried to experiment with:

1.Passing arguments to open file command (AddToRecentFiles:=False which added a negligible improvement if at all).

2.Setting Window.Visible = False to subroutines but then the macro does not copy any text.

I am not even sure what oDoc does in:

```
Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=vDirectory & vFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
```

Lots of Googling, copy-pasting with only basic knowledge. Sorry about that. But I am willing to learn.

```vb
'Create variables to use later
Dim vDirectory As String
Dim vFileTarget As String
Dim vStat1 As Variant
Dim vStat2 As Variant
'Variables to clear clipboard in case of errors
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub GoodStats()
vDirectory = "C:\Users\Job\Calculate\" 'Files to process
vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.docx*") 'Extension of the files to process
vFileTarget = "C:\Users\Job\stats.docx" 'File for the final count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
DeleteOld 'Prepare final count file for new calculation
Do While vFile <> "" 'Get this show on the road
Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=vDirectory & vFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
TextCopy
TextMove
vFile = Dir
Loop
'Proceed to next function because there are no files left to process
FinalRun
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function DeleteOld()
'Previous statistics is deleted from final count file
Documents.Open FileName:=vFileTarget
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
ActiveDocument.Save
End Function

'Primary cycle of document open, copy, paste begins
Function TextCopy() 'Copy text from right part of the table
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'Goes to error handler if there is no text on the right side
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:     'If there is no text, close document, proceed to next function
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Exit Function
End Function

Function TextMove() 'Move copied text to final count file
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Documents.Open FileName:=vFileTarget
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
ErrorHandler:     'If error, close document and move on
    Exit Function
End Function

Function FinalRun()
'Open the final count file to calculate statistics
Documents.Open FileName:=vFileTarget
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'Calculate number of symbols and spaces
vStat1 = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces)
'Translation pages = symbols + spaces divide by 1860
vStat2 = Round((ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces) / 1860), 2)
Selection.TypeText Text:=vStat1 & " symbols with spaces" 'First statistics line
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:=vStat2 & " translated pages"
'Money = pages multiplied by 10000
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:=vStat2 * 10000 & " rubles for all the translations"
ActiveDocument.Save
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **KazJaw** I now have the macro I want. Thanks a lot for directing me to the Range feature. The new macro does not copy files but calculates statistics from selections in each file one by one, adds all the numbers and displays the results in a message box. And it definitely feels faster.

**UPDATE 2**

I've added

```
Application.Visible = False
```

and the macro works like that. I've also added a timer to calculate the execution time and the macro now loops through 173 files in about 10 seconds :)

```vb
    Sub GoodStats()
'Create variables to use later
Dim vDirectory As String
Dim charCount As Single
Dim tcharCount As Single
Dim pageCount As Single
Dim moneyCount As Single
Dim myRange As Range
Dim startTime As Double
'Clear basic statistics number if you run macro multiple times
tcharCount = 0
startTime = Timer
'Folder to process
vDirectory = "C:\Users\Job\Calculate\"
'Extension of the files to process
vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.docx*")
'Don't want all those files popping up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Visible = False
'Get this show on the road
Do While vFile <> ""
Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=vDirectory & vFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
'Switch to the right column
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCell
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Start, Selection.End)
    'Get the initial number
    charCount = myRange.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces)
    'Add the current document stats to overall stats
    tcharCount = tcharCount + charCount
    ActiveWindow.Close
vFile = Dir
Loop
'Translation pages = symbols + spaces divide by 1860
pageCount = Round((tcharCount / 1860), 2)
moneyCount = pageCount * 10000
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Visible = True
Done = Timer - startTime
'Show the results in a message box with multiple lines
MsgBox tcharCount & " total characters" & vbCrLf & _
pageCount & " total pages" & vbCrLf & _
moneyCount & " total money" & vbCrLf & _
"Done in " & Done & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all- **opening and closing documents is time consuming!**

Second, **selecting** is usually inefficient way of working with Word documents, Excel ranges, Office shapes, etc.
Instead of that you could try to set reference to `Object Variable` and operate with your text by working with your `variable`. However, it requires some changes in your code and different approach.

Below you will find a part of your code (`Function TextMove()`) which I transformed from `Selection approach` to `Object Variable approach`. I kept your code (in comments) that you could compare what is instead of which part of the code. This code do the same but it should run much faster.

```
Function TextMove() 'Move copied text to final count file
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Documents.Open FileName:=vFileTarget
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

   'CHANGES AS OF THIS SECTION
        Dim myRange As Range
        Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
            'Selection.EndKey unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.EndKey(wdLine, wdExtend))
            'Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
        myRange.Font.Bold = wdToggle
            'Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdLine
            'Selection.TypeParagraph
            'Selection.TypeParagraph
            'Selection.TypeParagraph
        myRange.InsertBefore Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
            'Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
        myRange.MoveStart wdStory  '<< but you rather don't need it
   'END OF CHANGES 

    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
ErrorHandler:     'If error, close document and move on
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the information!
I was using Selection because this entire macro started as a compilation of the macros recorded by MS Word’s Record Macro feature with creative editing. I had no idea about Range. But it seems Range has some very interesting applications like Range.ComputeStatistics Method. I should probably dig it more and then maybe I don’t have to copy any text anywhere.